# Too many SOQL queries error encountered when running the class in Sandbox but not in Production

Tags: apex, unit-test, sandbox, failing-tests, apextestrunresult

I have experienced a bunch of test classes fail to pass in a Sandbox, but execute fine in Production.

Has anyone some good tips on what look out specifically? I think the code itself is not particularly of interest as I have almost 15 unit tests that present this error. All of them possess different logics.

**Note**
I keep on getting the error even when I run the tests individually or in a group.

Comment: You'll want to enable Profiling to determine the cause, and read the logs after running tests.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with Profiling?

Comment: Are you using seeAllData as true in your test class? Or any package which is installed just in prod but not in sandbox?

Comment: See [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2014/05/a-guide-to-application-performance-profiling-in-force-com.html) as an example of profiling (Developer Blog post).

Comment: 1. Debug logs are your friend. Read them. 2. @isTest(seeAllData = false) annotation on test class and methods is your another friend.

Comment: if you spin up a new sandbox from PROD and run the tests in that new sandbox - do they fail (unlikely). If they pass, then your failing sandbox is not a mirror of PROD in some respect (data, managed packages, custom metadata, tests that rely on org data).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would check:

1. If the tests are (@seeAllData= true)... if this is the case, you need to make your soql queries more selective
2. Are you using a testdatafactory? if so, check if someone messed it up recently
3. See if there's code that's recursively called, and should not be. So for example, do you have account updating all the contacts, which is updating the account, etc? If this is the case, you need to block the recursion.
4. Are you referencing global classes/ methods that are part of a managed package? The WSDL in Salesforce that you have in SF might be out of date (this is rare, but happens with products like Zoura..)
5. Check out profiling if all else fails - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2014/05/a-guide-to-application-performance-profiling-in-force-com.html

Comment: Points 1. is ruled out. Point 2. is a bit unclear what would this imply, as if it messed up, then it should be messed up in Production too. Am currently planning to be even more careful and debugging granurarly, following your and @sfdcfox's suggestion. Thanks for point 4., that maybe opens up a broader perspective.